# How do you say “whatsoever” in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In everyday language one often uses the word “whatsoever“ to emphasise, as in this example from daily life:

> There is no problem *whatsoever*.
>   I have no doubt about his work *whatsoever*.

or in scientific language one would say something like:

> This theorem would work for any dimension whatsoever.

For the first two examples one can argue that

> Es gibt überhaupt kein Problem.
>   Ich habe überhaupt keinen Zweifel an seiner Arbeit.

deem appropriate but that wouldn't work for the last one.

How would you translate it (in particular the last example) into German?

Comment: “This theorem would work for any dimension whatsoever.” isn’t exactly scientific language. The *whatsoever* serves no purpose whatsoever in a scientific context and can thus be omitted.

Comment: I should have said sciency language but the „*whatsoever*” that you use in your comment is the kind of „*whatsoever*” I am searching, which in your case roughly translates to „*überhaupt*”.

Comment: "Ich habe keinerlei Zweifel"

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I think that it is a thing in scientific context to not prove everything in detail or not in the general form, thus adding terms like `without prove` or `wlog` serve a purpose and carry a very similar if not equal meaning to `whatsoever` in this context: to communicate a short cut taken in the reasoning to keep the text from being bloated with proves.

Comment: @null: I fail to see that paralell. In the example sentence, *whatsoever* emphasises *any.* But that’s a tautology – the *whatsoever* does not add any information to the sentence. Thus at least in the soberness of a scientific context, it is not required. Note that this does not necessarily mean that *whatsoever* should not be used in scientific language at all: Sometimes without *whatsoever,* a statement may be misunderstood to be less universal than it is. But still, there is no connection to *without prove* or *w.l.o.g.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft isn't stating the obvious lack of a prove a tautology just the same?

Comment: @null: No, the *without proof* informs the reader that there was actually some proof omitted here. Thus the reader does not expect that what was not proven is obvious and also knows that there is no need to search for a proof. Thus this information serves some purpose (as does *w.l.o.g.*). The *whatsoever* in the example sentence, however, serves no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ok, from my understanding of the sentence it could serve that purpose.

Comment: This shows the problem with attempting word for word translation. It just doesn't work that way, except for (most) nouns. Always translate on a sentence basis and you won't be left wondering such things.

Comment: Add 'jegliche' and 'keinerlei' to your vocabulary..

Answer (score 13):

As a half-German (but only beginner-level speaker since moving to Germany a few years ago), I would say *überhaupt* is probably formally correct for *whatsoever*. In a more informal context, I would probably use the wonderful expression *gar* as in "Es gibt gar kein Problem."

I like it, because it sounds authentic, and would definitely use it in speaking. It's sort of the English equivalent to *absolutely* – "There is absolutely no problem".
*Gar* can make anything into its intensive form, as in "Es gibt gar keine freien Parkplätze" (="There is absolutely no open parking-place"), or "Das ist gar nicht wahr" (="This is absolutely not true"). If you speak Afrikaans or Dutch, it's equivalent to *glad* or *helemaal* respectively.

Comment: +1 for "gar". Totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 10):

It's probably closest to the truth to say that there is not one translation that works in all context. In essence, the word is an intensifier. It makes a statement sound more extreme by underlining that really all choices have been considered.
If its scope is more general and it can be replaced by "at all", then "überhaupt" is the best match.

> There is no problem **whatsoever** (at all).
>   Es gibt **überhaupt** kein Problem.

If the focus is more on items and it expresses the idea of "of any kind", then one of the following comes very close:

> There is no problem **whatsoever**(of any kind)
>   Es gibt **kein wie auch immer geartetes**/**keinerlei**/**nicht das geringste** Problem.

In the example with "work" all work pretty much the same

> Ich habe **überhaupt keine/keine wie auch immer gearteten/keinerlei/nicht die geringsten**...

If used in a positive sentence (like the dimension one) then some variation over "jed-" will do:

> ... würde in jedweder/jeder/jeder vorstellbaren Dimension...

Answer (score 4):

Since the *whatsoever* in the last example only adds emphasis, you can just omit it in the translation.

> Der Satz würde in jeder Dimension funktionieren.

(The word *funktionieren* is somewhat colloquial in this context.) Now if you want to add a similar emphasis you can say:

> Der Satz würde in jeder beliebigen Dimension funktionieren.
>
> Der Satz würde in jeder Dimension funktionieren, ganz egal welcher.
>
> Dabei ist die Dimension schnurzpiepegal, der Satz bleibt gültig.
>
> Dabei kümmert den Satz die Dimension nicht im geringsten (oder: nicht die Bohne), er bleibt wahr.

For some occasions these variants will not be equally suited.

Comment: *Im Satz ist die Dimension völlig Wurs(ch)t* might work, colloquially...  (Talking more seriously I rolled back to the original version, since the last "d/aa noneie"-edit didn't seem to make sense.)

Comment: I'd be pleasantly surprised if someone finds a published mathematical paper using the word "schnurzpiepegal".

Comment: @gnasher729, I got carried away a bit. But the “whatsoever” seemed already a bit colloquial.

Comment: Im mathematischen Kontext ist die Variante mit "in jeder beliebigen Dimension" die beste. Die anderen passen stilistisch nicht in einen wissenschaftlichen Text.

Comment: @MartinPeters, yes, I assumed a less formal presentation. Not all mathematics is written.

Answer (score 4):

*Whatsoever* can be translated as *sowieso, ohnehin* or *überhaupt*.

> Es gibt sowieso/ohnehin/überhaupt kein Problem.
>   Ich zweifle sowieso/ohnehin/überhaupt nicht an seiner Arbeit.
>   Das Theorem funktioniert sowieso/ohnehin/überhaupt in jeder Dimension.

Another option is *wie auch immer*:

> Wie auch immer, [rest of sentence]

*Sowieso* has more a meaning like *it does not matter*, positive or negative
*Ohnehin* sets more a negative precedent *well, there could be a problem, but it does not matter anyway*.
*Wie auch immer* means that you are inclined to end the discussion *well, whatever, but it’s enough, it does not matter*.
*Überhaupt* is even stronger, it really means *that it really does not matter and don’t dare to mention it again*. It can also be used if you are surprised or astonished about something: "Das funktioniert ja überhaupt nicht ! (That does not work at all !)".

Comment: *sowieso* could be translated as *in all cases/any case*, which fits quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of *whatsoever* may vary in English (probably a slang word).

> There is no problem *whatsoever.*
>
> I have no doubt on his work *whatsoever.*
>
> This theorem would work for any dimension *whatsoever.*

German, however, has rather explicit expressions:

> Es gibt *soweit* überhaupt keine Probleme.
>
> Ich zweifle *kein bisschen* an seiner Arbeit.
>
> Dieser Satz könnte *auf jegliche* Dimension angewandt werden.

Comment: I don't think "Es gibt soweit keine Probleme" is a suitable translation.

Comment: @Christian es sollte wohl besser `überhaupt keine` lauten, um es  ausdrücklich zu betonen.

Answer (score -2):

Whatsoever  = in keiner Hinsicht.

> Es besteht kein Problem in keiner Hinsicht.

Comment: Das halte ich nicht für idiomatisch. Wenn schon, dann "Es besteht in keiner(lei) Hinsicht ein Problem".

Comment: "kein Problem in keiner Hinsicht" verwirrt mich. Klingt wie "ich will nicht kein Bier trinken."

Comment: doppelte und dreifache Verneinung gibt es nur im bayerischen Dialekt...

Comment: @Emanuel wenn dann heißt das "Ich will kein Bier nicht trinken".